# vim can't edit tar files on osx

Tags: macos, vim, tar

Vim can view tar files (go ahead, open a tarball, it's pretty cool), it lets you navigate through the tarball and even open the files within. On linux systems I can edit these files and even save them! But on OSX I get an odd error:

```
***error*** (tar#Write) sorry, unable to update /ball.tar with file/in/tar.ball
```

Googling seems to fail me. In fact documentation I can find seems to indicate vim shouldn't even support editing these tarballs (though I can very clearly do it on multiple systems with the default vim installation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the version of `tar` that ships with OSX doesn't have a feature that's required for this (specifically: `--delete`, could be others as well but this one definitely)!

By installing (and using) the gnu version of tar, this will start to work. You can do this by installing `gnu-tar` with homebrew, though this installs it as `gtar` so to have vim use it you need to do one of two things:

- do the brew install with the `--with-default-names` flag
- modify your path to include the gnubin folder: `PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

**EDIT:**
As @Amadan mentioned in a comment, you can also add this to your vim config:

```
let g:tar_cmd="/usr/local/bin/gtar"
```

After installing `gnu-tar`, which will give you all the magic with no side effects.

Comment: Third option: `let g:tar_cmd="/usr/local/bin/gtar"`. Doesn't clobber your OSX tar, only affects Vim.

Answer (score 3):

Install GNU tar and use it in vim:

```
brew install gnu-tar
echo 'let g:tar_cmd="/usr/local/bin/gtar"' >> ~/.vimrc
```